# Can SQL Server automatically create a new data file when MAXSIZE is reached?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fast growing database. I make backups everyday but I want to avoid copying one large file daily. Rather, I want to have new data files automatically created (say, 10GB) so that I can create incremental backups and only copy the new files.

How do I do this? If I set a maxfile size, what happens when DB reaches this size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at differential backups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526.aspx

Comment: The problem is that the database is about to fill up the drive, so I want to stop THAT FILE from growing. I know how to create new data files manually but I don't want to do this continually(I don't want to have to watch the size of each additional file created). Instead, I want SQL Server to automatically create the additional files as they are filled(each 10GB only). e.g data1.mdf, data2.mdf, data3.mdf et.c. No human intervention. Just configure it once.

Answer (score 0):

Create full backup every week, differential backups every day, and transaction log backups every hour (if you needed it).

To restore the database you have to restore last full backup, all differential backups (from the moment of last full backup).

Comment: Ok, differential backups could work. The problem is that the database is about to fill up the drive, so I want to stop THAT FILE from growing.  I know how to create new data files manually but I don't want to do this continually(I don't want to have to watch the size of each additional file created). Instead, I want SQL Server to automatically create the additional files as they are filled(each 10GB only). e.g data1.mdf, data2.mdf, data3.mdf et.c. No human intervention. Just configure it once.